# How to pop self view controller when I click the cancel button at the search bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have created the search view controller to add the articles searched to the main view controller.
I wanna make it to pop itself from navigation view controller by clicking the cancel button of search bar. I have tried like as below:

```
- (void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*) searchBar {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

I need a help from everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that you are assign the searchBar Delegate to your viewController .. and also check the navigationController if its nil or not , then your code should work.

Comment: how to check navigationController is nil or not?

Comment: in the Xcode console, you can write 'po self.navigationController'